# What is the best practice for backing up a database in Simple mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

I am trying to create a SQL Job for backing up my database.  I want to have:

1. A weekly full backup
2. A daily differential backup
3. Something that will clean up backups that are older that 14 days

I [started doing this with the Maintenance Plan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/should-i-create-a-maintenance-plan-for-my-database-or-use-jobs), but decided managing it through jobs would be more flexible.

My questions are: how do I name the backup files?  Do I name them with a date naming convention and use the same convention to delete old files?  Is there an easier way?

If I'm over thinking this and should be using a Maintenance Plan, I would appreciate that answer as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend Ola's scripts for SQL Server maintenance - backups, re-indexing, checkDB, house-keeping, everything! It takes care of naming conventions too! They are very clever, and award winning too!!!! :)

Personally, if your databases are small, I'd keep to a full daily backup schedule. I believe Microsoft recommend that as well - simplicity is best approach.

Ola's scripts:
http://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Thanks so much for the help.